# How to debug an error in my linked list: "Error: Could not find or load main class RunTest"

Tags: java, class, linked-list, nodes

I encountered below error when compile my assignment (the code compile passed but bottom error came up right after)

```
mnt/ro/voccontent1/gradinglib/ccc_v1_c_48ao_206651/asn281740_9/
asn281741_1/asnlib.0/LinkedListTests.java:64: error: cannot find sym
bol                                                                 
            assertEquals("Julia", ( (LinkedList) list2).getTail().ge
tData(), "The tail shjould point at the node with data \"Julia\" ");
                                                                 ^  
      symbol:   method getData()                                    
      location: class Object                                        
    1 error                                                         
    Error: Could not find or load main class RunTest                
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RunTest
```

And Below is part from my starting code for a linkedlist.java, not sure where I got wrong to get above error, is it the way I construct getTail() method?

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

    
public class LinkedList<T> implements List<T> {
    
    private class Node{
        T data;
        Node next;

        Node(T data, Node next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
        Node(T data){
            this.data = data;
        }
        Node getNext(){
            return next;
        }
        
        T getData(){
            return data;
        }        
        
        void setNext(Node next){
            this.next = next;
        }
        

    }    
   
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int size;
    
   
    
    public T getTail(){
       
            return this.tail.data;
        }
    
    
    public T getHead(){
        
            return this.head.data;
        
    }
    
    public LinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }
    public LinkedList(Node head, Node tail, int size) {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
        this.size = size;
    }
    
    private Node getNodeAt(int index) throws Exception {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception("Linked List is Empty...");
        } else if (index < 0 || index >= this.size()-1) {
            throw new Exception("Your index is out of the list bounds");
        } else {
            Node retval = this.head;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                retval = retval.next;
            }
            return retval;
        }
    }
```

I tried to add getData in Node class but didn't work

Comment: If this is Java, add the Java tag to your question.

Comment: From the error message it looks like `getTail().getData()` is expected to return the data of the tail node, but your implementation of `getTail` returns the data, not the node. It would have been helpful if you woud include the literal code challenge description; then such things would have been clear.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is the part of getHead and getTai: A getter for the head instance variable named getHead
A getter for the tail instance variable named getTail.

Comment: I added below code, but still shows same error:public Node getTa() {
        if (size == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        Node current = head;
            while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        return current;
    }
 
    public T getTail() {
        Node tail = getTa();
        if (tail != null) {
            return tail.getData();
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: Can you add the code in `LinkedListTests`? It seems like the error(s) are in there.